# Android ListView - rough scrolling when GestureDetector is set

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, smooth-scrolling

I noticed that if I set a GestureDetector on a ListView (tried to detect a horizontal swipe on the list), the list stops scrolling smoothly. If you fling it, it sometimes stops scrolling as soon as you lift your finger.
Any idea why this happens and how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a little code of what you are doing?

Comment: It happens sometimes when your listview item/row contains number of childs (imageview, textview, checkbox). Another thing is due to low memory of device. These might be the reasons.